# Move unique_ptr outside of variant

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, variant

I have a unique_ptr inside a variant. I'm trying to do this:

```cpp
if(std::holds_alternative<std::unique_ptr<something>>(a_variant)) {
    auto thing = std::get<std::unique_ptr<something>>(a_variant);
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work, but how can I move the pointer outside of the variant?

Comment: You need to `move`  pointer, not copy.

Comment: `... = std::move(std::get<...>(...))`

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh so it's that simple. I guess you should post an answer so I can accept it because it solved the issue.

Comment: @user7860670 I know I have to move not copy, I just didn't think I can just call std::move on the output of std::get

Comment: You can `std::move(std::get<> ...` or `std::get<>(std::move(...`.  Either would work.  Move the variant or move the unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `std::move` the `std::unique_ptr` out of the `std::variant`.

```
struct something final {};
std::variant a_variant(std::make_unique<something>());

if(std::holds_alternative<std::unique_ptr<something>>(a_variant)) {
    auto thing = std::move(std::get<std::unique_ptr<something>>(a_variant));
}
```

Or, `auto thing = std::get<std::unique_ptr<something>>(std::move(a_variant));`

If you don't like `std::move`, you can use `std::shared_ptr` which is copyable.